# Excel VBA define a run variable

Tags: excel, vba, variables

i would like to define a run variable in sheet one Range A:A. The code shoud check in sheet one and sheet two in Range A:A which numer is assigned, to create the next larger number.

```
Dim last As Integer
    iLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    ' Definiere Bereich, indem Laufvariable eingetragen werden soll
    Dim nächster_Wert As Long
    nächster_Wert = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A:A"))
    
    ' Laufvariable prüft zellenwert und trägt nächsten Wert in Zelle ein
    Cells(iLastRow, 1).Value = nächster_Wert + 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: the code shoud check in sheet one in Range A and sheet two in Range A the MAx value

Comment: How can i realize that? After checking the maxvalue, i need max value +1 in sheet one as next value

Comment: That is not a question, that is a statement of a requirement. But what exactly do you need to know in order to fulfill that requirement?

Comment: First check max in sheet 1, then check max in sheet 2, then compare the two and add 1 to the higher one. Use that value.

Comment: My code is a kind of protocol. Each line has a log number. If I do not need the protocol with the protocol number, I store it in the archive sheet

Comment: Ok, i understand but i am not the vba specialist. So i cant realize that as a code

Comment: @Green I'm sure you know how to get Max from sheet2 so just do a `If..Then..Else` statement and compare both values?

Comment: i have MaxValue1 and MaxValue2 as variable which describe the maximum values from the two different sheets. now i have two compare the variables

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.